Customize Rundeck API Responses
I need to consult the job execution logs through the RUNDECK API. But when I receive the response I see workflow information, which is not very interesting for keeping the environment information safe. How can I remove this information from the API response?
Follow the API URL: https://localhost/443/api/45/job/4f68f5be-99d0-43d3-8856-37c30db64a14/executions
    <execution id='94' href='https://localhost:443/api/45/execution/94' permalink='https://localhost:443/project/DEV/execution/show/94' status='succeeded' project='DEV'>
        <user>admin</user>
        <date-started unixtime='1717526702426'>2024-06-04T18:45:02Z</date-started>
        <date-ended unixtime='1717526703174'>2024-06-04T18:45:03Z</date-ended>
        <job id='4f68f5be-99d0-43d3-8856-37c30db64a14' averageDuration='733' href='https://localhost/api/45/job/4f68f5be-99d0-43d3-8856-37c30db64a14' permalink='https://localhost:443/project/DEV/job/show/4f68f5be-99d0-43d3-8856-37c30db64a14'>
            <name>api_reference</name>
            <group></group>
            <project>DEV</project>
            <description></description>
        </job>
        <description>hostname</description>  #here is the command sent to the node#
        <argstring />
        <serverUUID>cae2da6d-58a8-4e25-b5f0-50021d454e7b</serverUUID>
        <successfulNodes>
            <node name='Egons' />
        </successfulNodes>
    </execution>

I tried to perform the API GET with a user with the lowest permission level. I expected that the workflow information would not be presented from the API get response
I want to remove the following part:
<description>hostname</description>  #here is the command sent to the node#


You need to post-process the default output via a XML parser like xmlstarlet or xq.
A xq example:
cat output.xml | xq -x 'del(.execution.description)'
Result:
<execution id="94" href="https://localhost:443/api/45/execution/94" permalink="https://localhost:443/project/DEV/execution/show/94" status="succeeded" project="DEV">
  <user>admin</user>
  <date-started unixtime="1717526702426">2024-06-04T18:45:02Z</date-started>
  <date-ended unixtime="1717526703174">2024-06-04T18:45:03Z</date-ended>
  <job id="4f68f5be-99d0-43d3-8856-37c30db64a14" averageDuration="733" href="https://localhost/api/45/job/4f68f5be-99d0-43d3-8856-37c30db64a14" permalink="https://localhost:443/project/DEV/job/show/4f68f5be-99d0-43d3-8856-37c30db64a14">
    <name>api_reference</name>
    <group></group>
    <project>DEV</project>
    <description></description>
  </job>
  <argstring></argstring>
  <serverUUID>cae2da6d-58a8-4e25-b5f0-50021d454e7b</serverUUID>
  <successfulNodes>
    <node name="Egons"></node>
  </successfulNodes>
</execution>

In your case, you can concatenate this post-processing to your API call. Something like:
curl xxx | xq -x 'del(.execution.description)'
You can check an xmlstarlet example here.

Thank you, but if a client consumes an API, there are no methods that guarantee that they will not see the "description" field, it will be necessary to make the correction after receiving the response.
